# How do I stop Xcode from changing '&gt;' to '>' and back

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

Every time I open a storyboard in Xcode it changes every instance of '$gt;' inside button titles to '>'. That would be fine, except when another developer open the same storyboard their Xcode changes it back. We're both running the Xcode Version 6.2 (6C131e). Neither of us can recall changing any settings related to this.

```
$ git diff
    -  <state key="normal" title="VERIFY CODE &gt;">
    +  <state key="normal" title="VERIFY CODE >">
```

How I can convince Xcode to stick with just one representation for '>' ?

Comment: Have you filed a bug with Apple? Sounds like something they should fix. Go to http://bugreport.apple.com